# XSLT. Сравнить значение атрибута с переменной

Tags: xslt

Пытаюсь разобраться с синтаксисом XSLT. Есть ли способ получить значение атрибута узла, по значению его другого атрибута, сравнив его со значением переменной?

Вот так работает:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text:section[@dc:class='q1']/draw:image/@xlink:href" />
```

А так - нет:

```
<xsl:variable name="my_var"><xsl:value-of select="@dc:group" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="text:section[@dc:class=$my_var]/draw:image/@xlink:href" />
```

При этом `<xsl:value-of select="$my_var"/>` выводит `q1`

Comment: Почему переменная определена так сложно? Чем вариант `<xsl:variable name="my_var" select="@dc:group" />` не устроил?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это уже от отчаянья) изначально определение было проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, трансформер пытается сравнить две XML-ноды по ссылке. Попробуйте одну из них явно преобразовать в строку:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text:section[@dc:class=string($my_var)]/draw:image/@xlink:href" />
```